# err_connection_closed after 20 minutes when loggedin in backend

Tags: errors

On a wordpress theme I created I have a strange behavior:

On one of many page, I get the error err_connection_closed after about 20 minutes of loading and no content is displayed. But only when I am loggedin in the backend. I don't get the error when I logout.

Other Pages of the same Wordpress Website work fine...

I could reproduce it in chrome and firefox so far (have no IE).

I have no idea where to start debugging this one - and since the thing runs on a hosted server, I cannot see the access-log, which is a shame - I know (btw. I cannot reproduce this error on the tetstserver, which also has a ssl certificate).

I don't do any extra things of which I know, where I even check if I am loggedin or not.

Can that be an SSL issue? (It seems to occure since we installed a certificate, but not sure)

Can that be an JS issue or is it more likely to be an issue of the server.
I don't get any other errors in the browser (console, or network)

[image]
[image]

Has anybody had a similar problem?

Comment: Have you tried loading those pages directly to see what happens? Is there anything in your PHP error/warning log that might be related? Is `/produktionen` your WP root folder?

Comment: Yes I checked that. Nothing. No it's a subpage

Comment: What's on that subpage though? Have you done the standard disable all the plugins and themes and reactivate them one by one? WP_DEBUG? XDebug? Are you sure both production and your test server have the same versions of PHP etc? 23minutes is a very long time, double check your PHP time execution limit is a normal value most pages stop after 30s to 1 min as a top value

Comment: Yes yes... The limit is by 2 minutes... I am really stuck.

Comment: I really appreciate your input though, keep shooting

Comment: Without seeing code there really aren't many paths to check, look for conditionals that check if you're logged in that run on that page, and start commenting out code for that pages templates until it works again. You haven't finished the debugging process, and so you really don't know what your question is until you've isolated the cause

Comment: It's hard to show code for me as the project is not public. 
And the code seems ok, because it works (on the test and local server the problem does not occure - so it's not neccessarily a code problem) and there are NO checks on the user-role or state in the code. 

So the question is ... how to debug such an issue on a higher level and pls. don't think I am new to php or wordpress only because of my 146 points here ... I asked the question because it is a real issue and hard to find where to start the highlevel debuggin.

Comment: I understand, and I wouldn't expect anybody to go through an entire codebase anyway, you're going to have to conduct a process of elimination, commenting parts of that template out until it starts working again to see what the culprit is, or the reverse, uncommenting until it breaks. If it's an SSL issue etc you should be able to tell by visiting the page and seeing what the chrome network tools say. Otherwise I'm afraid there really isn't much more anybody here can do without getting their hands on the real deal and spending an hour or two debugging

Comment: Put simply the problem needs to be identified before it can be solved

Comment: really :) that's what I am asking for ;) how to identify that one ... I would go further: if I can identify it, it will be 80% of the solution.

Comment: I am looking for somebody who observed a similar problem and can say what he/she did then ... it is a problem I don't know and you Tom too. So maybe there is someone who does?